# How to add the UserDocsWebPart to a page?

Tags: document-library, office-365

I am using O365. I have an existing site where I see some webpart with the latest documents. I did some investigation and this is the UserDocsWebPart. I created another site and would like to add the same webpart. But how to add this webpart to a page? I dont know which one I need to select from the ribbon. Does it has another title?

ps. my target is to show a list of the latest modified 5 documents

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by my self. It is the "Relevant Documents" WebPart which is available in the category "Content rollup".